# Javascript. Weird output when outputting Object's built-in functions from array

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

This example is based from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Refer to https://jsfiddle.net/bmswqgz7/1/

```
let ocn = Object.create(null);

Object.setPrototypeOf(ocn, Object.prototype);

//ocn.valueOf(); // shows {}
//ocn.hasOwnProperty("x"); // shows "false"
//ocn.constructor; // shows "Object() { [native code] }"

console.log([ocn.toString(), ocn.valueOf(), ocn.hasOwnProperty("x"), ocn.constructor].join(' : ')); // A

console.log([ocn.toString(), ocn.valueOf()].join(' : '));  // B
```

Here, line A outputs `": : false : function Object() { [native code] }"` and line B outputs `": [object Object]"`.

This is weird because in line A, `ocn.toString()` and `ocn.valueOf()` have no output and in line B, it outputs nothing for `ocn.toString()` and `[object Object]` for `ocn.valueOf()`, where we expect `ocn.valueOf()` to be `{}` and `ocn.toString()` to be `[object Object]`.

So it omits outputs in line A and output is out of order in line B.

Could someone explain this?

It works correctly if I output the values line by line: https://jsfiddle.net/bmswqgz7/2/

Thanks.

Comment: even if ocn.valueOf() it is an empty object ( {} ), when you joint it with " : " - which is a string, it gets casted to String and that's why it becomes "[object Object]"
for a simpler example, test this in the browser's console: var a = {}; console.log(a); console.log(a.toString()); console.log(a + " : ");

Comment: I cannot reproduce, I always get `[object Object]`

Comment: …in a normal console. You're right, the jsfiddle builtin console outputs really weird stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone explain this?

[JsFiddle's console is broken](https://jsfiddle.net/yswn9p3z/).

```
console.log("[object Object] : [object Object] : false : function Object() { [native code] }");
```

will output the garbled line, not the expected string.